# php cron job not working running script from CLI works fine

Tags: php, cron

I have a script which drives something in Suite CRM which I can run  easily from the command line by just typing php script.php.

However when I run it using the cron, it fails after the line

```
echo "Defined sugarEntry\n";
```

I have also tried hard coding the path in the require statements and also tried require_once.

I've also set the relevant include path in /etc/php.ini, and this is the php that is being used in the cron. Is there anything else I am missing?

```
   <?php
        //Don't forget to set the include path in /etc/php.ini
        echo "Start \n";

        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $full_path);

        echo "Include path set to " . get_include_path()."\n";
        //error_reporting(E_ERROR);

        if(!defined('sugarEntry'))
                define('sugarEntry', true);
        echo "Defined sugarEntry\n";

        require(  'include/entryPoint.php');
        echo "Entry point included\n";

        require(  'custom/modules/Accounts/controller.php');

        echo "Include file set\n";

        $controller = new AccountsController();

        echo "AccountsController initialised\n";

        //$controller->debug = true;

        //Loop through all the Accounts records that are a customer
        $controller->sync_all_crm_to_smb();

        echo "Finished\n";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring the necessary paths why don't you try with an easier way.
You can do the following in your crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * cd <path_to_your_script> & php <script_name>.php
```

I'm using */1 * * * * just for the example.

`<path_to_your_script>` is the path to the directory where you successfully execute the script through the console.

If this still doesn't solve your problem try this in your php script:

```
 #!/usr/local/bin/php
 <?php
 .......
```

Comment: 58 12 * * * cd <path_to_your_script> & php <script_name>.php  > <path_to_your_script>/smb_sync.log 2>&1.  This gives the following in smb_sync.log: Could not open input file: <script_name>.php
To rule out a permissions issue, I've set my script to 777.

Comment: Replace <script_name> with you script name

Comment: Do the same with path_to_your_script

Comment: Sorry, I did that already, was just using the same notation you used above.  So I am using actual paths and script names !

Comment: So now is there an error after you give 777 ? Although 766 should work also.

Comment: Yes, I can't understand it.

Comment: 58 12 * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/<not telling you>/httpdocs & php sync_all_crm_to_smb.php  > /var/www/vhosts/<not telling you>/httpdocs/smb_sync.log 2>&1
This is the actual command I am using, except of course I am not putting in the hostname.  The script file exists and is spelled correctly.

Comment: Yes exact same as before, could not open file.  Also the error is written to smb_sync.log.

Comment: let me check that - yes for u,g and o

Comment: Try replacing " ..... & php <script_name>.php" with "....... & /usr/local/bin/php <script_name>.php" Depending on the path to you php on the server

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: Ok, last shot add #!/usr/local/bin/php before <?php in the script ... I`ll put in the answer

Comment: No ... same problem still. I didn't think it would work since it can't find the script with #!/usr/bin/php (the path on my server to php) in it in the first place. Also tried putting in the full path in the cron and that just gave the original problem of not being able to include any files.  Thanks for your help though, can I give you a vote or something?

Comment: As you wish ... but this is very strange problem

Comment: What user do you run the cronjob, I guess the same you are logging?

Comment: root. Files in that folder are apache.